# eclipselink JPQL Cascade query probleam

Tags: jpa, null, eclipselink, jpql, cascade

**I have a problem  in JPQL cascade query with eclipselink2.5**

please see code

## Entity code

```
public class Category{
...
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category", referencedColumnName = "id")    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,optional = true)     
    private Category parentCategory;
...
```

}

## JPQL code

```
 String jpql = "select o from Category o order by o.parentCategory.sort ASC";
```

## problem

the problem is this JPQL return list does **not include 'o' if 'o.parentCategory' is null.**

please see this table    https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsXvk.jpg

```
the return list only rows id is 2,3,4 .

because the column parent_category is null, I lost rows 1,5,6  

the correct result should be return all rows

Looking forward to your help！
```

Answer (score 0):

Using o.parentCategory.sort in the order by clause forces an inner join which filters nulls.  If you want nulls included, you will need to use an explicit outer join in the query:

```
"select o from Category o outer join o.parentCategory parentCategory order by parentCategory.sort ASC"
```

Comment: thank you help, but if using outer join like your code, I get error message "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Comment: I don't see why the query would cause an oom exception.  Try using left join instead of outer join and Check the SQL generated if it gets that far, and that it is returning the number of results you expect.